# Who will take the strike if the striker is run out on the last ball of the over?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

What will happen in cricket in case of last ball run out scenario of the striker? Which batsmen will face the first ball of the next over?

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple. Just keep in mind that the new batsman will take the place of the dismissed batsman. If they have changed the strike, the new batsman will be on the strike in the next over, if they haven't, the new batsman will be on the non strike.

Answer (score 1):

Depends which end they were run out.

The new batsman always comes in at the end they were runout from. If they were runout at the strikers end, then the non-striker will be on strike for the first ball of the next over, as the new bowler will now be bowling from the end he was runout from, and the end the new batsman will be at. However if he is runout at the non-strikers end, the new batsman will be at the non-strikers end, but then it becomes the strikers end when the bowling changes ends, the new batsman is on strike for the first ball of the next over